# Some file require prompt for permission before deleting - OSX Macbook

Tags: macos, mac

On some files I am required to enter my credentials before deleting a file.  It only happens on some file in my Pictures folder.

I while back I created another user and moved all the files from my old user.  I ran the repair option from the boot menu and it did not seem to help.  I am running Mountain Lion.

I checked the permissions on one file I needed permission to delete and this is what I found:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ownership on the files is probably incorrect. The quickest way to correct the ownership issue is via Terminal.app. Since you've moved files from one user account to another, I'm assuming you have administrative rights.

In a Terminal, issue the following command to change the ownership of everything in your Pictures folder:

```
sudo chown -R /Users/<your_username>/Pictures
```

**More Detailed Instructions**

1. Open Terminal: <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> and type Terminal. Hit <kbd>⏎</kbd>(enter) when you see it highlighted.
2. Type `cd` followed by a space on the command line you are presented with
3. Open up a Finder window and drag the problematic folder to the Terminal window to insert the path. Hit <kbd>⏎</kbd>
4. Assure that you are in the appropriate directory by typing `pwd`<kbd>⏎</kbd>.  If your expecting to be in your Pictures folder, you should see `/Users/<your_username>/Pictures`
5. type: `sudo chown <your_username> ./*` and hit enter.  Replace  with your short username (i.e. the name to the left of the `$`).
6. Done.

Comment: How do I tell if this worked.  It only took a few seconds and I have about 50,000 pictures.

Comment: It's a fast operation.  If ownership was the issue, you should be able to operate on all files now.

Comment: @BoundforPNG The new picture you posted suggests that somehow custom Access Control Lists (ACLs) got set on some files. You may need to re-run ephsmith's instructions again, but for Step 5, do this: `sudo chmod -RN ./*`. This should remove all ACLs from all files in the directory sub-tree that you're in.